# change the values of rows according to an specific condition in R spark

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr

I have a dataset with information about health insurances. Im working with dplyr in R spark and I have to do this exercise:

analyze the age group from 14 to 64 years old, assigning people younger than 14 years old to 14 years and people older than 64 years old to 64. Show a graphical representation of the relationship between Age and average individual insurance rates.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.